# How do I set relative paths in PHP?

Tags: php

I have an absolute path of (verified working)

```
  $target_path = "F:/xampplite/htdocs/host_name/p/$email.$ext";
```

for use in

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $target_path
```

However when I move to a production server I need a relative path:

Comment: Why do you need this change? What OS is the production server running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `/archemarks` is at the root directory of your server, then this is the correct path.  However, it is often better to do something like this:

```
$new_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../images/" . $new_image_name;
```

This takes the directory in which the current file is running, and saves the image into a directory called `images` that is at the same level as it.

In the above case, the currently running file might be:

```
/var/www/archemarks/include/upload.php
```

The image directory is:

```
/var/www/archemarks/images
```

For example, if `/images` was two directory levels higher than the current file is running in, use

```
$new_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../../images/" . $new_image_name;
```

Comment: Note that, with PHP >= 5.3, you can use `__DIR__` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: Maybe a hint on `realpath` is worth the words to compact the path.

Answer (score 2):

```
$target_path = __DIR__ . "/archemarks/p/$email.$ext";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$target_path = "archemarks/p/$email.$ext";
```

notice the first "/"

/ => absolute, like /home

no "/" => relative to current folder

Comment: "Relative to root" is misleading, as it's more commonly known as "absolute" (_vs_ "relative" [to non-root]).

Comment: @Tomalak yeah, i changed it a bit, but still dosent feels all right :-/ changing it to absolute, thanks

Comment: BTW it's supposed to be "phoenix" :)

Answer (score 1):

That is an *absolute* path. Relative paths do not begin with a `/`.

If this is the correct path for you on the production server, then PHP may be running in a `chroot`. This is a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

Below is code for a php file uploader I wrote with a relative path.
Hope it helps. In this case, the upload folder is in the same dir as my php file. you can go up a few levels and into a different dir using ../

```
<?php
if(function_exists("date_default_timezone_set") and function_exists("date_default_timezone_get"))
@date_default_timezone_set('America/Anchorage');
ob_start();
session_start();

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/" . date("Y/m/d") . "/" . session_id() . "/";
if(!file_exists( $target_path )){
    if (!mkdir($target_path, 0755, true))
        die("FAIL: Failed to create folders for upload.");
}

$maxFileSize = 1048576*3.5; /* in bytes */ 

/* Add the original filename to our target path.  
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$index = 0;
$successFiles = array();
$failFiles = null;
$forceSend = false;
if($_SESSION["security_code"]!==$_POST["captcha"]){
    echo "captcha check failed, go back and try again";
    return;
}

foreach($_FILES['attached']['name'] as $k => $name) {
    if($name != null && !empty($name)){
        if($_FILES['attached']['size'][$index] < $maxFileSize ) {
            $tmp_target_path = $target_path . basename( $name );
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attached']['tmp_name'][$index], $tmp_target_path)) {
                $successFiles[] = array("file" => $tmp_target_path);
            } else{
                if($failFiles == null){
                    $failFiles = array();
                }
                $failFiles[] = array ("file" => basename( $name ), "reason" => "unable to copy the file on the server");
            }
        } else {
            if($failFiles == null){
                    $failFiles = array();
                }
                $failFiles[] = array ("file" => basename( $name ), "reason" => "file size was greater than 3.5 MB");
        }
        $index++;
    }   
}

?>

<?php 
    $response = "OK";
    if($failFiles != null){ 
        $response = "FAIL:" . "File upload failed for <br/>";
        foreach($failFiles as $k => $val) {
            $response .= "<b>" . $val['file'] . "</b> because " . $val['reason'] . "<br/>";
        }
    }

?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   window.top.window.uploadComplete("<?php echo $response; ?>");
</script>
```

Comment: Note chmod 0777 is a permissions security risk & blocked by many hosts, use 0755 for folders 0644 files, also note that your script would allow any filetype upload to succeed plus its moved out of temp before any checks are made. saving to common folder names like `./uploads/` `./upload/` `./files/` `./uploadedfiles/` will not protect the direct path very much.. not to mention the `c99shell` scripts pawning your server.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for the permissions advice. The script is not the final product but I was not aware of what the correct file permissions would have been. In this case the uploaded files had to be available on the internet and a random 18 character id is part of the final url to the files, apache is configured not to list directory contents and each dir has an empty index.html file. Is this sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the /archemarks directory is directly below document root - and your example suggests that it is -, you could make the code independent of a specific OS or environment. Try using

```
$target_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/archemarks/p/$email.$ext";
```

as a generic path to your target location. Should work fine. This notation is also independent of the location of your script, or the current working directory.